# Update second digit in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-update, sql-server-2000

How to update the second digit in a 16 digit number to '1' ?

This should be an easy one, but I have not had any luck.

I am working with SQL Server 2000 and 2005 (multiple environments - same database tables).

I searched for solutions online and found one that apparently would work in Oracle, but SQL Server does not like the pipe symbols when I run this:

```
UPDATE INTERFACE
SET OptionBits = substring(OptionBits,1,1)|| replace(substring(OptionBits,2,1), '0', '1')||substring(OptionBits,3, 14)
WHERE ObjectNumber = 5
```

I do only want to update the one there object number = 5 as you can see.

I looked into using `Replace` but that was not a solution either.

What is the trick?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The naming of the column suggests that you're actually storing *multiple* data items in a single column. This is usually a bad idea and leads to complex queries like this. It would be far better to use the data type that SQL supports for storing multiple items - the table. E.g. `CREATE TABLE Options (ObjectNumber int, OptionPosition int, OptionSetting bit)`.

Answer (score 2):

For MSSQL, [the `STUFF` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) is probably the best option:

```
UPDATE INTERFACE
SET OptionBits = STUFF(OptionBits, 2, 1, '1')
WHERE ObjectNumber = 5
```

Comment: Oh for heavens sake!  Now that you mention it that is perfect and I should have figured that out myself, I used that function before it's just that it was probably two years ago.

Answer (score 0):

The '||' symbol does string concatenation in Oracle.  The equivalent in SQL Server is `+`:

```
UPDATE INTERFACE
    SET OptionBits = substring(OptionBits,1,1) + replace(substring(OptionBits,2,1), '0', '1') + substring(OptionBits,3, 14)
    WHERE ObjectNumber = 5
```

Comment: Well thank you Gordon, I am now having to work with an Oracle DB sometimes as well so littel tid-bits like that will be quite useful.